# HDFGROUP.org vs. hdf5DotNet

Tags: .net, hdf5

I need to write a .NET app that converts a HDF5 file into its dictionary in my app.

I'm leaning toward HDFGROUP.org because they claim to have written HDF5 and offer it on NUGET.

hdf5DotNet seems good too.

I've you've had experience, which of these is faster to develop in, and were there reliability issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HDFGROUP NUGET fails to install into Visual Studio 2017 because it's not compatible with frameworks 4.0 through 4.6.1

Moving on to hdf5DotNet which installed.

Comment: Did you consider `HDF.PInvoke` also from **HDF Group**? As I understand, they recommend it over `HDF5.NET`. If you aren't familiar with it, it's discussed here: [HDF.PInvoke blog post](https://www.hdfgroup.org/2016/01/hdf5-net-one-step-back-two-steps-forward/)